# Permission denied to OldAccount even though I am working from NewAccount

Tags: git, github

$ git push origin master

ERROR: Permission to myuser/MyProject.git denied to OldAccount.
fatal: could not read from remote repository

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists

**I have already uninstalled my older Git and installed new Git. But that did not seem to work.
.gitconfig file has my new credentials. I have also singed up in git using new email id**

Comment: Try configuring your new email again using command:
git config --global user.email "your_email@abc.com"

Comment: There is not enough detail to answer your question. It boils down to a configuration of credentials on both the client and server end. There are many Stackoverflow questions and answers that already deal with this. You should probably go through all the steps *from scratch* for configuring remote git access. Unless you have details that make your situation truly unique, please look at existing questions. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=github+fatal%3A+could+not+read+from+remote+repository

Comment: Did you change remotes?

Comment: Your `.gitconfig` file never contains credentials. Git itself does not have or store them. Credentials, if and when they are stored, are stored by programs that *are not Git* and therefore in files that *are not Git configuration files*. Are you using HTTPS or SSH? What operating system do you use? Those are the key questions. Git will run various "credential helper" programs for some protocols (https on some OSes) and rely entirely on ssh itself when using ssh.

Comment: Note that the `user.name` setting is not a credential and has nothing to do with this. The `user.email` setting is not a credential and has nothing to do with this.